# How can I process financial stock data before passing it to an LSTM for time series classification?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, keras

I'm trying to make an LSTM that can classify the next day of a stock as either 1 or 0 for going up or down. The issue I've been having is that Keras tuner seems to stay at a constant value of val_loss not matter the hyperparameters I use. It also tends to always classify stocks as 1 meaning it has an accuracy of roughly 50%.

I beleive the issue lies in how im processing my data before it is passed into the LSTM. Generally, stocks tend to go up over a long time scale meaning that I have a lot more 1's than 0's (the data is non-stationary). I have therefore tried to difference my time-series before I scale it between 0 and 1. The issue with this method is that as the stocks value increases over the years the difference in stock values varies much more. This means that when i scale it all the values at the start of the series are close to 0 and at the end of the series they are close to 0 or 1.

I have therefore tried scaling the data in windows but this doesnt seem to work either. Would anyone be able to offer advice on what the best method to solve this issue is?

````
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_ta as pta
import pandas_ta as ta
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

companies = ['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'META','MSFT','GOOG','NVDA','TSLA','VWAGY']

data = pd.DataFrame()
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
history = "max"
scaling_window = 300

for company in companies:
    stock = yf.Ticker(company)
    symbol = stock.ticker
    new_data = yf.download(tickers = symbol, period = history)
    new_data['Company'] = company
    new_data.reset_index(inplace = True)
    new_data['RSI'] = ta.rsi(new_data['Adj Close'], length=15)
    new_data[['RSI']] = scaler.fit_transform(new_data[['RSI']])
    # new_data['EMAM'] = ta.ema(new_data['Adj Close'], length = 100)
    # new_data[['EMAM']] = scaler.fit_transform(new_data[['EMAM']])
    new_data['Adj Close'] = new_data['Adj Close'] - new_data['Adj Close'].shift(-1)
    for i in range(0, len(new_data), scaling_window):
        window = new_data.loc[i:i+scaling_window-1, 'Adj Close']
        window = window.values.reshape(-1, 1)
        scaled = scaler.fit_transform(window)
        new_data.loc[i:i+scaling_window-1, 'Adj Close'] = scaled

#remove the time from the datetime because otherwise it causes issues later down the line with merges
data['Date'] = data['Date'].dt.tz_localize(None)

#get the price of gold
gold_ticker = 'GC=F'
gold_prices = yf.download(gold_ticker, period = history)
gold_prices = gold_prices.filter(items =['Date', 'Adj Close'])
gold_prices['Adj Close'] = gold_prices['Adj Close'] - gold_prices['Adj Close'].shift(-1)
gold_prices[['Adj Close']] = scaler.fit_transform(gold_prices[['Adj Close']])
gold_prices.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'Gold Price'}, inplace=True)
gold_prices.reset_index(inplace=True)

#get the price of brent (proxy for oil)
brent_ticker = 'BZ=F'
brent = yf.download(tickers = brent_ticker, period= history)
brent = brent.filter(items = ['Date', 'Adj Close'])
brent['Adj Close'] = brent['Adj Close'] - brent['Adj Close'].shift(-1)
brent[['Adj Close']] = scaler.fit_transform(brent[['Adj Close']])
brent.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'Brent Price'}, inplace = True)
brent.reset_index(inplace = True)

new_data = pd.merge(data, gold_prices, on='Date')
new_data = pd.merge(new_data, brent, on='Date')

new_data['ClassNextDay'] = new_data['Adj Close'] < new_data['Adj Close'].shift(-1)
new_data['ClassNextDay'] = new_data['ClassNextDay']*1

new_data.dropna(inplace = True)
new_data.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'index'], axis =1, inplace= True)

new_data = new_data[['Adj Close','RSI', 'Company', 'Gold Price','Brent Price','ClassNextDay']]


path = 'C:/Users/goldn/Desktop/final project/data.csv'

new_data.to_csv(path, index = False)```
````